# Format data to JSON like format

Tags: java, json

I'm using a charting library that needs that the input looks like some format. This format looks like JSON but it isn't, and here I share some data to get an idea about the format:

```
[{
                    year: 2005,
                    income: 23.5,
                    expenses: 18.1
                }, {
                    year: 2006,
                    income: 26.2,
                    expenses: 22.8
                }, {
                    year: 2007,
                    income: 30.1,
                    expenses: 23.9
                }, {
                    year: 2008,
                    income: 29.5,
                    expenses: 25.1
                }, {
                    year: 2009,
                    income: 24.6,
                    expenses: 25.0
                }];
```

You can see the complete example in [this link](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript/column-and-line-chart-mix/).
In my first test, I've used `String.concat(anotherString)` but I assure you that it's not comfortable. So is there any java API that provides this format?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is close enough to JSON that I bet it will accept JSON.  The only thing that makes that invalid JSON is the lack of quotes around the key names.

Comment: That looks like JavaScript, as opposed to JSON. If that's true, you should be able to use JSON in its place and have everything just work.

Comment: The lack of quotes around the key names is from Javascript. This is taken straight from a javascript example. If it **does** require this format, just use a json formatter then do jsonString.replace("\"", "")

Comment: Yes, the format is very similar to JSON except the quotes, but using the JASON format for the 3rd library causes exceptions, that's why I'm lookink for something that helps

Comment: where are you reading the data from ? (database?, beans ?) ... if its beans i would either overwrite the `toString()`method or create another one that writes the `{year:...,income:...,expenses:...` part and then use a for loop, to add the commas ... if its from a database it could be part of a query ... it depends

Comment: Is StringBuilder/StringBuffer what you you are looking for? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Very good idea from @Joel. I've never used any JSON library, so could you afford me what's the most comfortable lib?

Comment: Oh great idea @jambriz! In fact the dao returns List<SomeObject>. So in the SomeObject class, I can override the toString and that will do the job! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well, the only difference between that format and JSON looks like you just need to remove double quotes from the strings. So data.replaceAll("\"", ""); shall do the job.

but actually, reading the example, it shall accepts valid JSON. You shall try using a $.ajax() method, something that would look like :

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {$.ajax({
       url: '/mydata/',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: undefined,
       success: function(chartData) {
                // SERIAL CHART
                chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
                chart.dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.categoryField = "year";

                // AXES
                // category
                var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
                categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

                // value
                var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
                valueAxis.stackType = "regular";
                valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
                valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
                chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

                // GRAPHS
                // first graph    
                var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Europe";
                graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
                graph.valueField = "europe";
                graph.type = "column";
                graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                graph.lineColor = "#C72C95";
                chart.addGraph(graph);

                // second graph              
                graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "North America";
                graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
                graph.valueField = "namerica";
                graph.type = "column";
                graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                graph.lineColor = "#D8E0BD";
                chart.addGraph(graph);

                // third graph                              
                graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
                graph.title = "Asia-Pacific";
                graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
                graph.valueField = "asia";
                graph.type = "column";
                graph.lineAlpha = 0;
                graph.fillAlphas = 1;
                graph.lineColor = "#B3DBD4";
                chart.addGraph(graph);

                // LEGEND                  
                var legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
                chart.addLegend(legend);

                // WRITE
                chart.write("chartdiv");
            });
       }
     });
```

(sorry, I'm far from being good at writing javascript, but I think the idea is there). Also, maybe the API of amCharts enables you to direcly check a local URL. And then, you'll only have to route your JSON data as a REST call.

Comment: Sorry @zmo, but I don't understand what do you mean by the $.ajax() method??

Comment: well, the idea is to use jquery's $.ajax() method call that can download and deserialize some server's JSON data from whithin a javascript service on the client end point. The only thing, is that javascript code tend to be very ugly (imho) :)

Comment: OK I got the point. This would be a good idea if I were using native javascript in the client side, but in my case I'm using GWT that force me to use its remote call methods. Thank you any way for your help.

Comment: well, I don't have much experience with GWT, but I'm pretty sure it should cover that kind of workflow...

Answer (score 0):

chk this API's data related blog page

```
http://blog.amcharts.com/2011/03/amcharts-javascript-tutorials-part-2.html
```

I think this tutorial tells about all the nitty gritties of handling the data in this API, with lots of examples and code snippets

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simple:

var chartData = eval(json_data);

Best Regards